# failed to set a KeyComparator function

Tags: java, hadoop, mapper, reducers, secondary-sort

I'm trying to sort the data by value

The method i use is to combine the key and value to a composite key

e.g (key,value) -> ({key,value},value)

and define my KeyComaparator which is compare the value part in the key

my data is a paragraph that i should count the words

and i done two job, the first one do the wordCount, but combine the key to composite key in reducer.

this is the result

> is,4    4 
>   the,15   15 
>  
>   ECA,1   1  
>   to,6    6 
>   .....

and in the second job, I try to use the composite key to sort by the value

this is my mapper2

```
public static class Map2 extends MapReduceBase
    implements Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable>{

            private Text word = new Text();
            public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text,IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
                    String line = value.toString();
                    String w1[] = line.split("\t");
                    word.set(w1[0]);
                    output.collect(word,new IntWritable(Integer.valueOf(w1[1])));
            }
    }
```

and here is my Keycomparator

```
public static final class KeyComparator extends WritableComparator {
    public KeyComparator(){
            super(Text.class,true);
    }
@Override
public int compare(WritableComparable tp1, WritableComparable tp2) {
    Text t1 = (Text)tp1;
    Text t2 = (Text)tp2;
    String a[] = t1.toString().split(",");
    String b[] = t2.toString().split(",");
    return a[1].compareTo(b[1]);


}
```

this is my reducer2

```
public static class Reduce2 extends MapReduceBase
    implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

            public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException{
                    int sum=0;
            while( values.hasNext()){
                    sum+= values.next().get();
            }
            //String cpKey[] = key.toString().split(",");
            Text outputKey = new Text();
            //outputKey.set(cpKey[0]);
            output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
            }

    }
```

here is my main function

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            int reduceTasks = 1;
            int mapTasks = 3;

            System.out.println("1. New JobConf...");
            JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCountV2.class);
            conf.setJobName("WordCount");

            System.out.println("2. Setting output key and value...");
            conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

            System.out.println("3. Setting Mapper and Reducer classes...");
            conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
            conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

            // set numbers of reducers
            System.out.println("4. Setting number of reduce and map tasks...");
            conf.setNumReduceTasks(reduceTasks);
            conf.setNumMapTasks(mapTasks);

            System.out.println("5. Setting input and output formats...");
            conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
            conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);


            System.out.println("6. Setting input and output paths...");
            FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
            String TempDir = "temp" + Integer.toString(new Random().nextInt(1000)+1);
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(TempDir));
            //FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf,new Path(args[1]));
            System.out.println("7. Running job...");
            JobClient.runJob(conf);
            JobConf sort = new JobConf(WordCountV2.class);
            sort.setJobName("sort");
            sort.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            sort.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
            sort.setOutputKeyComparatorClass(KeyComparator.class);
            sort.setMapperClass(Map2.class);
            sort.setReducerClass(Reduce2.class);
            sort.setNumReduceTasks(reduceTasks);
            sort.setNumMapTasks(mapTasks);
            sort.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
            sort.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
            FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(sort,TempDir);
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(sort, new Path(args[1]));
            JobClient.runJob(sort);


    }
```

but the result is kind of this

> is 13 
>   the 32 
>   ECA 21 
>   to 14 
>   .
>   .
>   .

and lost many word

but if i didn't use my Keycomparator

it returns to the result which is not sorted, just like the first one i mentioned

any ideas to solve the problem? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you are making mistake.
But what you are trying to do is called `Secondary Sort` Sorting based on value.
It's not a trivial job to do, but you need to create more classes for patition,aggregation and other stuff which is clearly explained [Here](http://vangjee.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/secondary-sorting-aka-sorting-values-in-hadoops-mapreduce-programming-paradigm/)  and [Here](http://riccomini.name/posts/hadoop/2009-11-13-sort-reducer-input-value-hadoop/)
Just following the instructions in those blogs will surely help you.

Comment: thanks for help,
but I want to sort all the value without grouping them like the first link
, do I still need to do partition?

Comment: thanks, it works, but I still don't know why those two (partition,grouping) is necessary.